# Does exporting VueJS components worked differently than in ordinary javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, export

Exporting and importing components in VueJS seems to work differently than in ordinary ES10 Javascript. When it comes to Javascript, I'm used to thinking of exporting as working only on the object being exported. For example, if we have the following in a file:

```
export class Foo {
...
}

export class Bar {
...
}
```

You can import these separately like so:

```
import { Foo, Bar } from './FooBar.js';
```

What gets exported/imported is just whatever class is being exported/imported. But in VueJS where we export the main object controlling the component, we also seem to export the template and the styles. IOW, everything in the file seems to be exported.

I'm guessing it's all in how the VueJS compiler compiles the code, but I'm curious as to what exactly the compiler does such that 'export' in VueJS means export not only the script object but the template and styles too.

Comment: if you're referring to a `.vue` file, then the contents are *compiled* - so what is *actually* exported is the JS-only version of the template+script - which you seem to have said, so what's the mystery?

Comment: Only JavaScript can be exported.  The hidden process of turning a `.vue` file into a component is done by Webpack / [Vue loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/#what-is-vue-loader).